# How to escape correctly querySelector() characters

Tags: javascript, css, escaping

I have iframe with id = `google_ops_iframe_/15465462/cor.it_320x320_domestic_mobile_OF_0__container`

How to escape this id's characters to be able to select this element with `querySelector()`?

I've tried following with no luck:

`var elem =  document.querySelector("#google\\_ops\\_iframe\\_\\/15465462\\/cor\\.it\\_320x320\\_domestic\\_mobile\\_OF\\_0\\_\\_container");`

Comment: `google_ops_iframe_\\/15465462\\/cor\\.it_320x320_domestic_mobile_OF_0__container`. Escape only `/` & `.`.

Comment: @Tushar,you can put it in the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I start with the obvious, but this line work:

```
document.getElementById('google_ops_iframe_/15465462/cor.it_320x320_domestic_mobile_OF_0__container');
```

You don't have to escape characters when using `getElementById`.

But if you really have to use `querySelector`, the problem is with `/` and `.` characters. So your selector should be `#google_ops_iframe_\\/15465462\\/cor\\.it_320x320_domestic_mobile_OF_0__container`

Here a working example:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#google_ops_iframe_\\/15465462\\/cor\\.it_320x320_domestic_mobile_OF_0__container'));
```

```html
<iframe id="google_ops_iframe_/15465462/cor.it_320x320_domestic_mobile_OF_0__container"></iframe>
```